# Laplace Transform of $\int_{0}^{t}u^2e^u\,du$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

Good day,

I am having some problems with the Laplace transform of $f(t) = \int_{0}^t{u^2e^u\textrm{d}u}$.
$$\mathcal{L}\left [\int_{0}^t{u^2e^u\textrm{d}u}  \right ]$$

using the property :

$$\mathcal{L}
\left [\int_{0}^{t}f(u)\mathrm{d}u \right ] =
\frac{F(s)}{s},s>\textrm{max}\left \{ 0,a \right \}$$

This is what I have tried so far :

- $$\int_{0}^{t}u^2e^u\textrm{d}u = e^tt^2-2te^t+2e^t-2 \textrm{ (Integration by parts)}$$
- $$\mathcal{L}
  \left [e^tt^2-2te^t+2e^t-2 \right ] = \frac{2}{(s-1)^3}-\frac{2}{(s-1)^2}+\frac{2}{s-1}-\frac{2}{s}$$
- $$ \frac{\mathcal{L} \left [e^tt^2-2te^t+2e^t-2 \right ]}{s} = \frac{2}{s^2(s-1)^3} $$

**The solution of the problem is :** $$\frac{2}{s(s-1)^3}$$

Thanks in advance,

Emanuel Camacho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not use the suggested property. Since:
$$ \mathcal{L}(t^2 e^t) = \frac{2}{(s-1)^3},\tag{1}$$
it follows that:
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(\int_{0}^{t}u^2 e^u\,du\right) = \frac{2}{s(s-1)^3}.\tag{2}$$
To prove $(1)$, you just have to recall that $\mathcal{L}(t^2)=\frac{2}{s^3}$.

Comment: Why are you considering $u=t$ ?

Comment: @EmanuelCamacho: don't you get it? The property is telling you that in order to find the Laplace transform of a primitive, you just have to compute the Laplace transform of the integrand function, then divide it by $s$.

Comment: Aaahhh ok. I thought that in order to find the Laplace transform of a primitive, I had to do the Laplace transform of the primitive, and not only the integrand. Thanks @Jack D'Aurizio :)